# Rankings in first page of search results but getting almost no traffic?

Tags: seo, google-search, ranking, traffic

I'm working on the ecommerce rossanoferretti.com and I'm trying to improve the SEO. I'm in the first page for some specific key phrase that could potentially drive 500K users to the website, but the traffic doesn't increase at all. How it is possible? Here is the key phrase, potential monthly traffic, google page, link position

```
colour maintenance shampoo,     100K, page1, link 7
protective detangling spray,    120K, page1, link 2
shining oil,                    320K, page1, link 4
colour maintenance conditioner, 50K,  page1, link 1
```

Somebody can explain me why I have just only 200 visitors/day?

Comment: From where you got monthly traffic stats? semrush or Keyword planner? because I did not figure out that stats anywhere. I suggest to submit your website on Google Webmaster Tools, and analysis your search query, you will get better ideas about all the thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Your monthly search estimates are way off.   Google Adwords Keyword planner shows only one of those with enough volume to even count:

[image]

I used quotes around the keywords to get "exact match" which most closely simulates ranking for that exact phrase.

You can sign up for [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) which will tell you what you are ranking for, give you an average position, and give the number of monthly Google searches for the keywords.

In a specific position you also only get a fraction of traffic.  Link 2 is only going to get 15% and link 7 is only going to get 3%.   Here is a graph from [an article about it](https://moz.com/blog/google-organic-click-through-rates-in-2014):

[image]

Bottom line is, you are lucky to be getting 200 visitors a month if that is what you are ranking for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I didn't use the quotes ... I'm new to SEO and I make huge mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would do the following:

- Check the search volume and competition on Google Keyword planner, like you've done.
- Verify that my results show up in all locations, and not just in my own country results. (Search volume changes by location)
- Go to `Google Webmaster tools` > `your porperty` > `Search traffic` > `Search analysis` and see the impressions and CTR for that search term.

Basically in the above steps you are finding out the following:

1. What are the maximum impressions my web page can get?
2. Are the maximum number for the world larger than my own country, and does my web page show up everywhere?
3. What are the impressions that my page is seeing for that search term?
4. If my web page is being shown YY times, what percentage of people are clicking on it?

---

Secondary :

Check the bounce rates for those pages with organic as a source, in GA, and track this. Make sure it doesn't go down.